# Will adjusting the value acquired from bounding box annotation train the model to be able to make inferences?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai, google-ai-platform

This may be a silly question but I've been annotating quite a few documents with the Google Document AI tool and have had this worry in the back of my mind. My task is to use Doc AI to extract information from utility bills but a lot of the bills that I've been given have things missing like periods to indicate a decimal place, etc. I've been creating the bounding boxes around the text that I need to capture and then would go in and adjust the value manually by adding something like a period.

For example, below is a screenshot of a bounding box I've created around the `"0 0497160"` that's tied to the `Rate` field. It initially just captured the text as `"0 0497160"` but I went ahead and added the period between the first and second 0 as I know that's what the rate **should** be.
[image: example of adjusting value manually]

I've been manually adjusting values for the fields I'm capturing and I was under the assumption that the tool, when trained, will be smart enough to recognize that things like a period are missing and add those details itself. But as I've done a ton of annotation now, I'm worried that won't be the case.

Will doing this *train* the model to recognize that a decimal should be added in these instances for when I go ahead and test it?

Comment: which processor are you using and training? Have you defined the schema before the labeling process? Your case might be a bit tricky, if you define your label as Number (see here https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/docai-custom#5) , it might not format the bounding box to handle the preceding 0s. One trick you might do is through post-processing, which you programmatically update the document AI output JSON to format the floating numbers based on your format.

Comment: @Gang Chen - I'm using a custom extractor and for the `Rate` field listed above it's defined to be a Number. I have defined the schema prior to the labeling process as well. There are other fields that I have down as Number that also have this missing decimal issue. Would it be best to just have these fields be Plain Text and then handle the conversion in post-processing as you've said?